# php check if user is currently logged in

Tags: php

Hi I have built a site which runs several cron jobs which send users emails if they have a notification. It will be annoying to get such emails if the user is currently logged in using the site.

Is it possible to check whether a user has an active session on the server with php? When users are logged in they are given a $_SESSION['id'] var with their user id stored. Is it possible to check if the server currently has that the user id stored as an active session variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes it is possible**

PHP saves the active session data for each user in a temporary folder on the server. You can find the folder by looking into your php.ini configuration file under the variable session.save_path or simply run the following PHP command to get your active session data. The data is serialized so your going to have to deserialize it and parse it out.

```
<?php

print_r(scandir(session_save_path()));

?>
```

**scandir** 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

**session_save_path** 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: un-serializing session data is a non-trivial task.  That is without updating the session.